# Vb.net DataGridView column not displaing value

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I've looked through the forums and can't seem to find anything that helps me with this. I am pulling a time from SQL in a decimal format, don't ask me why, I know it doesn't make much sense to do that, especially when there is a time variable, or even chars.  Anyways, the format is HH.MM.  When I pull the data from SQL, I put it into a string, with a little formatting, and add it into a column in a datagridview.  The issue is that when added to the datagridview, it doesn't display. The value is there, I can output it via message box or console, but it just doesn't show up.  Any tips? I think it may have something to do with the way I am assigning the value to the cell, but I may be wrong as obviously I can't figure it out.

```
Public Sub RefreshRoutes()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim row As DataGridViewRow
    Dim iHour, iMinutes As Byte
    Dim dTime As Decimal
    Dim sTime As String
    Dim i As Short
    dgvRoutes.Columns.Clear()

    If Form1.SQLCon.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
        Form1.OpenDatabase()
    End If


    cmd = New SqlCommand("Pull_Detailed_Routes", Form1.SQLCon)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    Dim Adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 300
    Adapter.Fill(ds, "DataSet")
    Adapter.Dispose()
    cmd.Dispose()
    dgvRoutes.DataSource = Nothing

    dgvRoutes.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    dgvRoutes.Columns("ID").Visible = False
    dgvRoutes.Columns.Add("Time", "Start Time")
    'dgvRoutes.Columns("StarTime").Visible = False
    ds.Dispose()
    For i = 0 To dgvRoutes.ColumnCount - 1
        dgvRoutes.Columns(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro
    Next

    'dgvRoutes.Columns.Insert(2, TimeColumn)
    For i = 0 To dgvRoutes.RowCount - 1
        row = dgvRoutes.Rows(i)
        sTime = ""
        dTime = row.Cells("StarTime").Value
        iMinutes = (dTime Mod 1) * 100
        iHour = dTime - dTime Mod 1
        If iHour < 10 Then
            sTime = "0"
        End If
        sTime = sTime & iHour & ":"
        If iMinutes < 10 Then
            sTime = sTime & "0"
        End If
        sTime = sTime & iMinutes
        dgvRoutes.Rows(i).Cells("Time").Value = sTime
        'MsgBox(row.Cells("Time").Value.ToString)
    Next
    dgvRoutes.Columns("Time").DisplayIndex = 10


End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: That bit of code works for me. I have tested by having the Time column as part of the SQL table and I have tested by having a manual column which I added to my DGV in the design. How is the Time column added to the DGV? Is it a manual column or is it part of the same SQL DT as the StartTime column? Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: I'm not receiving any errors, and the code has been added with the full subroutine.

Comment: OK I'm going to ask as I don't know. Is the line `dTime = row.Cells("StarTime").Value` correct or should it actually be `dTime = row.Cells("StartTime").Value`?

Also have a look at putting the routine in a Try Catch to see if there are any errors as sometimes an exception won't occur during debug.

Comment: Haha, yes the column name is actually StarTime in SQL server, that part is correct.  Nothing I do seems to allow the data to display.

Comment: OK. Just had to check :) It works fine for me that code however and I am able to display the end result in the "Time" column. I wonder if any properties on the DGV have been set that could cause this although I can't think what. Could try `dgvRoutes.EndEdit()`

Comment: Just gone through the properties on the DGV and the only way I could make the column Time not accept the value is if I set **VirtualMode = True**. It's a long shot but has this property been set to True?

Comment: Thanks Jinx. The VirtualMode property is unfortunately set to false, so this is not the cause either.  I have gone through the SQL database and set the StarTime variable to a time now, so I can now read directly from the database, so my issue has been resolved.  I appreciate the help though, so thank you very much.

Comment: Not a problem. Glad you've sorted it. Weird controls at times are DGVs.